# Remote Desktop to my local network via VPS

Tags: vpn, vps, wireguard

I'd like to ask you for tips how to connect via RDP to my home network PC.

My current setup:

I have configured VPS server with WireGuard VPN running on it. I have added two peers there:

1. Personal laptop
2. RaspberryPI that is located in my home network and is permanently connected to the VPN

How it works now: I can connect to the VPN from my personal laptop from any place and then I am able to SSH to the RaspberryPI and since I am inside RaspberryPI I can see all my home network devices which is great.

My goal: I'd like to connect my personal PC to the VPN and be able to enter e.g. 192.168.1.1 to the browser and be able to display my router config page.

In other word I'd like to route all my local network addresses through the VPN to the RaspberryPI which can route it to my local network. Problem is that RaspberryPI is just configured as a regular peer. Maybe I need to configure it as a router or something like that?

I would be glad for ani tips! Thank you.

[image: Connection scheme overview]

### UPDATE - all my WireGuard configs included.

### WinPC client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXX
Address = 10.66.66.2/32, fd42:42:42::2/128
DNS = 9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1
PostUp = "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\vpn-up.bat"
PostDown = "C:\Program Files\WireGuard\Data\Configurations\vpn-down.bat"

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXX
PresharedKey = XXXXXXXXXX
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = XXXXXXXXXX


PostUp
@echo off
route -p ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.66.66.3 METRIC 10

PostDown
@echo off
route DELETE 192.168.0.0
```

***Block all untunneled traffic checkbox is checked.***

### RaspberryPI client

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXX
Address = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128
DNS = 9.9.9.9,1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXX
PresharedKey = XXXXXXXXXX
Endpoint = XXXXXXXXXX
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

***In sysctl.conf I only uncomment ipv4 forwarding: net.ipv4.ip_forward=1***

**Kernel IP routing table: *netstat -rn***

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
```

### WireGuard VPS

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.66.1/24,fd42:42:42::1/64
ListenPort = 53032
PrivateKey = SPnAugHnka45RWLzrDWBeAt8GA2e92yLVf6jeHXy0kw=
PostUp = iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53032 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 53032 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

### Client Windows Laptop
[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXX=
PresharedKey = XXXXXXXXXX=
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2/32,fd42:42:42::2/128

### Client RPi server
[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXX
PresharedKey = XXXXXXXXXX
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128,192.168.1.0/24
```

**Kernel IP routing table: *netstat -rn***

```
0.0.0.0         192.XXX.XXX.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp1s0
10.66.66.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wg0
169.YYY.YYY.254 192.XXX.XXX.1   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 enp1s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wg0
192.XXX.XXX.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 enp1s0
```

***In sysctl.conf I only uncomment ipv4 forwarding: net.ipv4.ip_forward=1***

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Routing on WireGuard network

Add `192.168.1.0/24` (your home network) to the `AllowedIPs` setting on the connection from your Personal Laptop to your VULTR VPS, and also on the connection from your VULTR VPS to your RaspberryPI.

The WireGuard config on your Personal Laptop should look something like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private key for Personal Laptop>
Address = 10.66.66.2

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key for VULTR VPS>
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24
Endpoint = <VULTR VPS IP address and port>
```

The WireGuard config on your VULTR VPS should look something like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private key for VULTR VPS>
Address = 10.66.66.1
ListenAddress = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key for Personal Laptop>
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.2

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key for RaspberryPI>
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.3, 192.168.1.0/24
```

The WireGuard config on your RaspberryPI should look something like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private key for RaspberryPI>
Address = 10.66.66.3

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public key for VULTR VPS>
AllowedIPs = 10.66.66.0/24
Endpoint = <VULTR VPS IP address and port>
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

#### 2. Routing on home network

Add a route for `10.66.66.0/24` (your WireGuard network) to the router for your home network, using the IP address of the RaspberryPI on your home network as the gateway. If the IP address of your RaspberryPi on your home network is `192.168.1.123`, and your router's LAN interface is `eth1`, the route would look something like this:

```
10.66.66.0/24 via 192.168.1.123 dev eth1
```

However, if you're unable to add routes to the router on your home network, you could instead add a masquerading iptables or nftables rule to your RaspberryPI (to masquerade packets from the WireGuard network with the Pi's own IP address when forwarding them to your home network); something like this would do the trick:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

Edit regarding your WinPC routing issues:

1. You don't need to run any special route commands on your WinPC in general -- you'd need them only if you're trying to test things out when you're already connected locally to the same network as you're trying to connect to remotely -- so you probably don't want to add any route commands to your WireGuard config (just run them separately when testing).
2. When testing locally, don't route the entire 192.168.0.0/16 network to the WireGuard interface -- a) it won't override the more-specific routes you probably have for the local network in the system's route table, and b) if it did work you would also block the route to your Internet gateway (probably 192.168.1.1). Instead, try just adding a route to one or two specific test IPs (eg if a device on your home network that you want to connect to is 192.168.1.123, add a route just for 192.168.1.123).
3. When testing, don't use the `-p` flag (you don't want to persist your changes across reboots).

Comment: The route for `10.66.66.0/24` can be added on the respective host in the local network as well. (It's in fact even more ideal than adding it on the router.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see above. I added all my current configs. I have exact same settings like you in the example except "Routing on home network" step. When I try to ping some local address form my client windows PC I still get the local answers - the local IP is not "searched" through the VPN server and I am not really sure how to add route on Windows machine. I have some .bat scripts but don't really know if it works.

Comment: Edited with some suggestions for testing.

Comment: @vviston You mean the two local networks have conflicting IP subnet?